# Update jQuery-highlightTextarea on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to update the jQuery plugin ["highlightTextarea"](http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/index.html) on the fly, but it is not working as I want it to.
I can initialize the textarea as expected, but the textarea does not care about the updates.

```
<textarea id="textarea">this is a test</textarea>

$('#textarea').highlightTextarea({ words: ['this'] }) // <--- working
$('#textarea').highlightTextarea({ words: ['is'] }) // <--- not working
$('#textarea').highlightTextarea({ words: ['a'] }) // <--- not working
```

I prepared a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqLp6p0d/1/) for you. Hope anyone can help me with that issue. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the solution: 'destroy' the textarea first. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqLp6p0d/2/)

Comment: It seems that you have to insert all words to be highlighted at once, so "this", "is" and "a" must be passed onto highlightTextarea alltogether.

Comment: From an example linked to on the plugin's docs (https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/dMLBpg) there is a note stating that you cannot dynamically update a selected range: `There is no way to remove highlights with this plugin, so you can not update the search term of options dynamically`. If you need this behaviour you'll need to extend this plugin yourself to clear selections, or find a different one which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, it's one-time use only. I guess the simplest way is to make a backup of the textarea, then replace the `<div>` created by the plugin with the backup before showing the next highlight.

Comment: You need to `destroy` it, first https://jsfiddle.net/oqLp6p0d/2/

Comment: It´s THAT easy?!? Oh man. Thanks a lot. :) @Hackerman

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out, reading the plugin code on github :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the `destroy` option first:

```
$('#textarea').highlightTextarea('destroy')  
$('#textarea').highlightTextarea({ words: [split[counter]], wordsOnly:true })
```

In order to check how that option works, you can look at the line `185` at https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea/blob/master/jquery.highlighttextarea.js

<kbd>[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oqLp6p0d/2/)</kbd>